# Windows "not genuine" after entering several commands

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, windows-genuine-advantage, windows-activation

After entering these commands:
bootrec.exe /FixMbr 
bootrec.exe/FixBoot 
bootrec.exe/RebuildBCD 
bcdedit /export C:\BCD_Backup
c: 
cd boot attrib bcd -s -h -r 
bootrec /RebuildBcd

My windows claims to be "not genuine" and I have 30 days to fix it... Does anyone know what I did to mess it up? and how I can reverse it?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you have a genuine copy of windows which you installed yourself? (The latter because I know at least one person who had a legal windows install. A 'helpful cleanup' from a tech at work replaced that with an illegal copy of windows and a crack in the bootloader.  I dDo not ask me why, maybe the tech did not have the right CD to work with the CoA on the bottom of the laptop). Anyway, the point is that if there was a crack installed via the bootloader you just wiped it.

Comment: +1 for plain and simple. if you own the registry key of a genuine windows 7 use it. otherwise.... well, lets not go into illegal territory.

Answer (score 6):

Search for `cmd.exe`. Right click and "Run as Administrator". Then type the following: `slmgr /ipk XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXX` where the XXXXX's are your product key for Windows 7. After the command completes (you get back to the prompt), restart the computer. Then tell Windows to activate. If it does not work, call Microsoft and explain to them that you had to reactivate your Windows after repairing Windows. If you have a real copy and the documentation to prove it (Certificate of Authenticity, disk, box, etc.) they should be able to help you reactivate Windows.